# Multiple SSIS Package errors

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that was built 3 years ago by someone else that is long gone. I have ran it multiple times over the past year, and now I am getting these errors and I do not know why they are coming up. This ssis package imports from an excel doc to a temporary table. Once the info is on the temp table the second time it is run, it takes from the temp table and inserts it with additional columns into the production table. These are the errors I am getting:

```
[OLE DB Destination [162]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has 
occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult:
0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".

[OLE DB Destination [162]] Error: There was an error with input column "UserProfileID" (299) on 
input "OLE DB Destination Input" (175). The column status returned was: "The value violated the 
integrity constraints for the column.".

[OLE DB Destination [162]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The
"input "OLE DB Destination Input" (175)" failed because error code 0xC020907D occurred, and 
the error row disposition on "input "OLE DB Destination Input" (175)" specifies failure on 
error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be 
error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on 
component "OLE DB Destination" (162) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input 
"OLE DB Destination Input" (175). The identified component returned an error from the 
ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will
cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with 
more information about the failure.
```

When I saw "error with input column 'UserProfileID'" i looked at it in the temp table and it is null. This is one of the columns that the package is supposed to find when it is run. But I don't know if that info is found with the second run or if it is supposed to populate the first time. So I am unsure if that is what the problem I am having is.

I appreciate any help that I can get. If any additional info is needed I can try and provide it. Thank you to anyone that can offer help.

[image: Importing from Excel File to temp table]
[image: Importing from Temp table to real table]
[image: Data Flow]

Comment: Post some screenshots of the control flow and data flows so we can get an idea of what's going on. Table structure of the staging and actual table won't hurt either. Please ;)

Comment: Alright, working on that now, thank you.

Comment: One thing you can do to see what is happening is to put a data viewer on the data flow to see what data is being sent. This will help you debug. Right clieck onteh green line and select Data viewer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Has the table had it's structure changed recently? If the field did not have a constraint before, and has one now, then you need to address the issue in your SSIS package to move any records which do not meet the constraint to an exception table or you need to find out why the constraint was added when it is not appropriate for the type of data being imported.

The next place I would look is the Excel file. When a package has been running a file for some time and suddenly has problems and there have been no changes to the structure of the table the data is being inserted into, then it is likely the data in the file is wrong.

Comment: The structure of the tables have stayed the same. And the file I have been assured has no mistakes in it, because that is the first thing I do when I get some misc rows that do not get imported. I asked for the maker of the file to look it over twice now to make sure there were no mistakes in the first row, as that would cause the whole thing to not import.

Comment: You know what, I went back and looked at the file myself this time, and with the little knowledge of the file that I have found one slight error on all the rows.. I brought it to the attention of the other person that had assured me it was right, and showed her. Thank you for making me second guess it. I now have another problem but this will be the answer for this. Thank you again!

Comment: @JoeW, one thing to take awy from this is that you always examine the file yourself. You tell the provider that the file is bbroken and why not ask them to verify if it is ok. They will often say everything is fine without looking at it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the important part of the message is:

```
"The value violated the integrity constraints for the column."
```

Does your destination allow null values in that field?
Can you insert the row manually?
If you take out the rows with null values in that field, does it run successfully?

re: your comment 
*the file I have been assured has no mistakes in it*
If you can identify rows that won't import because of null values in a field, can you send that set back and ask the guy if the rows are valid, because they're breaking the import?

OK, from your additional information, I can see the problem is the null value in the userProfileID field which doesn't allow nulls.  The question then becomes, what process is supposed to correctly determine the userProfileID value?  Is it the updateIDs step?  Is it copied directly from the Excel input file?

Comment: There are some allowed as nulls, but the ones that are not allowed as nulls are nulls. And its all rows that have the null values, not just some. Thats whats getting me stuck, I have never seen it return all null values for those columns

Comment: the problem may be upstream, then.  Check the source data and make sure it's getting populated correctly.

Comment: Ok, I am trying to do this, but I am fairly new to the ssis. I went into the data flow for the task "Import Temp data into real table" and in the OLE DB Source under there error out put it has all the columns listed and for the error it says "fail component" truncation says: "fail component" and description says: "conversion". On the destination the error output lists no columns but has the error fail component and description of insert. I don't know why there would be a conversion error since its going into a table with the same datatypes for each column. Does this help you see a problem?